# sender class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Anyone know how to get the sender class/module in ruby?

caller[0] is helpful to derive the filename and linenumber sending.

But knowing the class would be helpful. Can't find it any searches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be impossible. You shouldn't be specialising your behaviour in a method based on the calling class anyway.

Think about it this way - the caller could be an anonymous function (`proc`) created in one class, then given to another one and invoked from a third place. You wouldn't get anything useful.

Instead, I'd look at what you're trying to achieve here, and think of another way to get there! :)

Comment: Thank you Arlen. Good to know that is not possible. Just something I'm used (Smalltalk) to for debugging, dev dumps. It would be interesting to see what Smalltalk does for your case above; can't remember, ahve to try it. thx again.

Comment: @Gary: Aahhh, Smalltalk has this? Interesting! I guess its object model is a bit more well-defined and rigid than Ruby's, so I guess it's a more common thing. I step away from this conversation further enlightened. :-)

Comment: Sometimes people aren't building what you think they are building. In general using __sender__ is not recommended, but sometimes people are building auto loggers or profiles or something you could never think of.

Comment: @zachaysan: too true!

Answer (score 3):

Check out this gem: https://github.com/asher-/sender

Comment: Gem seems to have stopped working before ruby 2.6.6