# How to find the caller class in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

```
class A
  def bar
    B.new.foo
  end
end

class B
  def foo
    #Here
    "HELLO WORLD!"
  end
end

A.new.bar
```

Inside `B#foo`,
how can I find the `class A` or any other reference or class name.
Basically from which class it was called.

I tried something like this:

```
self.class
#B
self.class.superclass 
#Object
```

Comment: Did you tried `caller.first`?

Comment: Tried but it gives method 
caller - ```/Users/vikas/Desktop/Test/friend.rb:31:in `bar'```
caller.first - ```/Users/vikas/Desktop/Test/friend.rb:43:in `<main>'```

Comment: This might an answer that you need. It uses an approach that involves overriding `new` method of `Class` to track classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679969/get-caller-class

Comment: Well, the possibilities can be narrowed by defining `foo` thusly: `def foo; method_name = caller[0][/\`\w+'/][1..-2].to_sym; ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.instance_methods.include?(method_name) }; end`. `A.new.bar` causes `method_name #=> :bar` and returns `[A]`. If other classes have a method `:bar`, those classes  will be included in the array returned by `A.new.bar`. If you try this at home you will need to unescape the backtick above. (I escaped it so it could be seen.)

Answer (score 0):

To get the whole stack I usually do:

```
caller.select {|x| x.include?("my_string") }
```

where `my_string` is the name of my project