# Can I call a referring class in a service object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, service-object

I have a service object called from many different classes. Is there a way to call the referring class without passing it like this?

```
class Document
  ServiceObject.new('Document', id)
end
```

Can I refer to `self` or `super` or something in `ServiceObject`?

Comment: You can take a look at the https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller gem. I think it offers what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it natively, but there is a [gem](https://github.com/asher-/sender) for it according to [sender class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116525/sender-class-in-ruby)

Comment: Surprised it's only in a gem. Thanks!